# Dropdown Menus in Selenium - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to access a dropdown menu using selenium for HTML that looks like this:

```
<span class="k-pager-sizes k-label">
<span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="8e90d557-7e8d-4c5c-b906-202fd78c6d0a"><span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-input">20</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span>
</span>
</span>
<select data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
 <option value="10">10</option><option value="15">15</option>
 <option value="20">20</option><option value="50">50</option>
 <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
 <span>items per page</span>
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/opusandcaymus/Election/chromedriver')
    driver.get('http://mcad-tx.org/Property-Search-Result?searchtext=Maple%20Branch')
    #dropdown=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="grid"]/div[3]/span[2]/span/select')
    #select = Select(dropdown)
    dropdown = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    for row in dropdown:
        print(row.value)
    driver.close()
except:
    print("error")
    driver.close()
    raise
```

Does anyone know how to find the options by the values?  I want to select 100 every time the page is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select dropdown is hidden  so for that i would suggest first make it visible using javascriptexecuter then select the value

Use below code :

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@data-role='dropdownlist']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: block;')",element)
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_value("100")
```

And The other way is use `Explicitwait`
First click on down arrow and of dropdown and then click on value 100

Something like below code in python :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='grid']/div[3]/span[2]/span/span/span[2]/span")))
element.click

element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//ul[@data-role='staticlist']/li[5]")))
element.click
```

Note : please make correction as per python syntax

Comment: Flawless.  Thanks for both answers.  I'm still learning how to use JavaScript in Selenium from Python.  Very helpful.